# Android: convert Parcelable to JSON

Tags: android, json, gson, parcelable, parceler

I am working with socket.io library which emits messages to the socket.io server. The server expects JSON objects, arrays, etc. My original implementation used JSONOject and JSONArray datatypes. However, I would like to switch to using classes generated via [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) library. The classes generated with library's annotations can be wrapped into Parcels. It seems like a very convenient way of managing such communication. However, is there a way to convert Parceler's class or a Parcel class into a JSON string or JSONObject/Array?

GSON library supports `toJson` method and I know that Retrofit does some magic with Parcels, JSON, and GSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i guess this will help you,

Create a class with getters and setters method for example

```
class A
{
int b;
void setb(int x){this.b = x;}
int getb(){return this.b}
}
```

than you can create json from the object of this class:

```
new Gson().toJson(a)
```

Or object from json:

```
a = new Gson().fromJson(data, A.class);
```

Comment: Yep, this worked for me. I read the documentation but didn't get to try it before.