# it is impossible to convert JSON into an java object using GSON and RETROFIT

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I use Retrofit in my project. And i have problem. My JSON not convert to object.

Here it is my JSON:

```
{"id":1,"facebookId":"123","uuid":"xU71niPhrqzFqmBFhk5fl4LlvWg6zk42ENG4iMjgl3eJEb9LAcqVcc9NmLHzFIgg","userInfo":{"id":1,"user":null,"email":"IP696@mail.ru","firstName":"Pavel","lastName":"Petrashov","name":null,"dob":null,"gender":null,"facebookLink":"link","locale":null,"location":null,"timezone":null,"verified":null,"updatedTime":null},"balancedCustomer":null,"session":{"id":1,"session":"FTKuyeb1BXBzXRZzsAuwPYs4eRIpdi2Z","expirationDate":1424839445000,"ip":null,"user":null}}
```

Here it is my Retrofit method:

```
public ApiUser getApiUser(){
        if (null == apiUser) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
            RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.ROOT_URL_SKIP)
                    .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson));
            builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

            RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
            apiUser = restAdapter.create(ApiUser.class);
        }
        return apiUser;
    }
```

and i get this error:

```
Error: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1424839445000
```

My classes look like this:

```
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends Model {

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "facebookId")
    @SerializedName("facebookId")
    private String facebookId;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    @SerializedName("uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "userInfo")
    @SerializedName("userInfo")
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "balancedCustomer")
    @SerializedName("balancedCustomer")
    private BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "session")
    @SerializedName("session")
    private Session session;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public String getFacebookId() {
        return facebookId;
    }

    public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
        this.facebookId = facebookId;
    }

    public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public BalancedCustomer getBalancedCustomer() {
        return balancedCustomer;
    }

    public void setBalancedCustomer(BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer) {
        this.balancedCustomer = balancedCustomer;
    }
}
```

edited, this whole class.

```
@Table(name = "Sessions")
public class Session extends Model {

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "session")
    @SerializedName("session")
    private String session;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "expirationDate")
    @SerializedName("expirationDate")
    private Date expirationDate;
```

...

Comment: Show all variable declaration in `User` class

Comment: other classes with the same annotations. All types of the same names.

Comment: where is `expirationDate` field ?

Comment: added. in class Session

Comment: Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671373/unparseable-date-1302828677828-trying-to-deserialize-with-gson-a-millisecond

Comment: yes most likely a problem with the date. could give an example for my code? because in the example of the link is not all clear

Answer (score 1):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
                public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                    return new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong());
                }
            }).create();
```

thanks for the link @Deepak Bala
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671373/unparseable-date-1302828677828-trying-to-deserialize-with-gson-a-millisecond)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to get `expirationDate` with Date object because in `json` it is like unformatted.what you should do ,receive like string or double in `model` classes then inside application you can change or parse to date format.

```
    @Expose
    @Column(name = "expirationDate")
    @SerializedName("expirationDate")
    private String expirationDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get `expirationDate` as `long` instead of `Date` :

```
    @Expose
    @Column(name = "expirationDate")
    @SerializedName("expirationDate")
    private long expirationDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28496138/4373925)

Let me know if you face any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type of the `Session->expiryDate` to Long or String then when u want to convert that to a `Date` object just use this.

```
Date date=new Date(expirationDate);
```